# Playwright with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, playwright

My test report /html-result/index.html works whereas the files present under the trace folder display  a blank screen. How to actually setup the trace viewer?

NOTE: I would not able to host it via the localhost. Can you please let me know how to resolve this?
Below, is my publish html report stage.

publishHTML(
allowMissing: false,
alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
keepAll: true,
reportDir: 'html-Result/',
reportFiles: 'index.html',
reportName: "Playwright Report",
traceFiles: 'html-Result/data/**/*.zip'
)

```
        // Archive the HTML report as a build artifact
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: "html-Result/*.html", followSymlinks: false, onlyIfSuccessful: false
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: "html-Result/data/*.*", followSymlinks: false, onlyIfSuccessful: false
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: "html-Result/trace/*.html", followSymlinks: false, onlyIfSuccessful: false
```

the trace viewer zip is not opening in the browser. This is the URL I am trying to reach

https://ci-cloud.us.oracle.com/jenkins/ou/job/QA-OGL-PW-AUTOMATION-TESTRUN/315/artifact/html-Result/trace/index.html?trace=https://ci-cloud.us.oracle.com/jenkins/ou/job/QA-OGL-PW-AUTOMATION-TESTRUN/315/artifact/html-Result/data/29ca8ce13847d1ed509a82d94c04768d0c97bee7.zip

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your Oracle Jenkins instance blocks proxying JavaScript artifacts. See browser console and network request failures for details

https://trace.playwright.dev/ - try to upload your traces there directly instead

Comment: The problem is its not advisable to download the zip and upload it to https://trace.playwright.dev/. Is there any other way?